# Determine if all IDs in the column of one data.frame are in a column of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have two data.frame tables in R. Both have IDs for users who took particular actions. The users in the second table *should* all have done the actions in the first table, but I want to confirm. What would be the best way to determine if all the IDs in table 2 are represented in table, and if not what IDs aren't?

**Table A**

```
**Unique ID**    **Count**
abc123           1
zyx456           15
888aaaa          4
```

**Table B**

```
**Unique ID**    **Count**
abc123           1
zyx456           1
zzzzz123         2
```

I'm trying to get a response that abc123 and zyx456 in Table B are in Table A and that  zzzzz123 is not represented in Table A but is in B (which would be an error, since all B should be in A).

Comment: `TableB[,1]%in%TableA[,1]` will give True if present and false otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `%in%` operator to see which are in both versus those that are not:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tribble(~ID, ~Count,
               'abc', 1, 
               'zyx', 15,
               'other', 3)

df2 <- tribble(~ID, ~Count,
               'abc', 2,
               'zyx', 33,
               'another', 334)

match <- df2[which(df2$ID %in% df1$ID),'ID']
notmatch <- df2[which(!(df2$ID %in% df1$ID)),'ID']
```

This outputs two comparisons that you can use to check for values in a function and pass errors if need be:

```r
match
 A tibble: 2 x 1
  ID   
  <chr>
1 abc  
2 zyx  


notmatch
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  ID     
  <chr>  
1 another
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an efficient one-liner in base R:

```
setdiff(TableB$ID, TableA$ID)
```

It will return an empty result if everything in TableB is in TableA, and return the missing fields if there are any.

Other answers  may be better choices with broader context, but this is a simple solution for a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with a join in the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

JoinedTable = full_join(
  x = TableA %>% mutate(in.A = TRUE),
  y = TableB %>% mutate(in.B = TRUE).
  by = "UniqueID",
  suffix = c(".A",".B")
)
### Use whichever of the following is applicable
## Is in both
JoinedTable %>%
  filter(in.A, in.B)
## In A only
JoinedTable %>%
  filter(in.A, !in.B)
## In B only
JoinedTable %>%
  filter(!in.A, in.B)
```

Use a `full_join` to intersect the tables; set "by" to your ID column and adding a suffix to differentiate other columns that aren't unique to a particular column. I've added mutates to make the filtering code more clear, but you could also just look for NAs in the respective Counts columns (i.e. `filter(!is.na(Count.A), is.na(Count.B))` to find ones in A but not B).

If you just want a vector of the ones that meet each condition, just tack on `%>% pull(UniqueID)` to grab that.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. I hadn't tried this type before and this worked well, too!

Answer (score 2):

You can add another column to table B show if it is also in table A. Here is the code can make it (assuming `dfA` and `dfB` denote tables A and B):

```
dfB <- within(dfB, in_dfA <- UniqueID %in% tbla$UniqueID)
```

gives

```
> dfB
  UniqueID Count in_dfA
1   abc123     1   TRUE
2   zyx456     1   TRUE
3 zzzzz123     2  FALSE
```

**DATA**

```
dfA <- structure(list(UniqueID = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("888aaaa", 
"abc123", "zyx456"), class = "factor"), Count = c(1L, 15L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

dfB <- structure(list(UniqueID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("abc123", 
"zyx456", "zzzzz123"), class = "factor"), Count = c(1L, 1L, 2L
), in_dfA = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do an update join to see which IDs are/aren't in the first table

```
tblb[tbla, on  = 'UniqueID', in_tbla := i.UniqueID
     ][, in_tbla := !is.na(in_tbla)]

tblb

#    UniqueID Count in_tbla
# 1:   abc123     1    TRUE
# 2:   zyx456     1    TRUE
# 3: zzzzz123     2   FALSE
```

Not sure if that's any better than @Onyambu's suggestion though (same output)

```
tblb[, in_tbla := UniqueID %in% tbla$UniqueID]
```

Data used:

```
tbla <- fread('
UniqueID       Count
abc123           1
zyx456           15
888aaaa          4
')

tblb <- fread('
UniqueID       Count
abc123           1
zyx456           1
zzzzz123         2
')
```